# Select its generated element component, possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this component to render a form, but in same it has its form "catcher"

```
var FormUpload = React.createClass({
                    submit : function(){
                     var formdata =new FormData();
                     // I want to select form that generated by this self component.
                },

                render : function(){
                    return (
                    <form id="form" ref="uploadForm" className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data">
                    </form>
                    );
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html):

> If you need to imperatively perform an operation, you have to obtain a
>   reference to the DOM node. For instance, if you want to imperatively
>   submit a form, one approach would be to attach a ref to the form
>   element and manually call form.submit().

```
submit : function() {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    this.form.submit(); // access reference here                   
},

render : function() {
    return (
        <form id="form" ref="uploadForm" 
            className="uploader" 
            encType="multipart /form-data"
            ref={function(form) { //add reference here
                this.form = form;
            }}
        >
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks!, but I've seen many statement that using ref for accessing component instance is a bad idea, do you know how to this at the proper way? that will be a lot help!